# Why does this HABTM relationship defined in the fixtures does not run properly in this test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, has-and-belongs-to-many, fixtures

I'm using Rails 3.0.9.

I have this fixtures defined:

treatments.yml

```
treatment5:
  id: 5
  code: T2
  description: "Inclusión en la política de seguridad directrices para el teletrabajo"
  reduction: 0.2
  document: "D01_Politica_Seguridad"
  account_id: 2
  soa_lines: soa_line5
```

soa_lines.yml

```
soa_line5:
  account_id: 2
  id: 5
  justification: "El teletrabajo introduce riesgos adicionales que deben gestionarse"
  control_id: 2
  applicability: true
  treatments: treatment5
```

And models have:

treatment.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :soa_lines
```

soa_line.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :treatments
```

But in test,

```
treatment = treatments(:treatment5)
treatment.soa_lines # Returns []
```

Why does treatment.soa_lines return []? Is the HABTM no well defined in the fixtures?

Comment: As a forward note, you can set multiple associations using an array[] ie: `soa_lines: [soa_line5, soa_line6]`  Hope that answers why treatment.soa_lines returns [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't set an **id** on your model if you want to use the named fixtures on **HABTM**:

```
treatment5:
  code: T2
  description: "Inclusión en la política de seguridad directrices para el teletrabajo"
  reduction: 0.2
  document: "D01_Politica_Seguridad"
  account_id: 2
  soa_lines: soa_line5

soa_line5:
  account_id: 2
  justification: "El teletrabajo introduce riesgos adicionales que deben gestionarse"
  control_id: 2
  applicability: true
  treatments: treatment5
```